# PHP curly braces inside strings colour in Notepad++

Tags: php, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I want to colour variables inside curly braces in PHP strings
For example

```
echo “My variable is {$myvar->myArray[$something]}”
```

Currently I have the Obsidian theme, and something like this displays as the following image shows:
[image]

You can see that the variable inside the strings is not coloured when embraced by curly braces. The variable that’s not embraced in curly braces is coloured though, because it has an entry in the php style configurator: the STRING VARIABLE (as you can see in the next picture).

Now, I know that there are a lot of different keywords in PHP language that are being used in the WORD style in php language in Notepad++. Just go to langs.xml, under the “php” language with the keywords name “instre1”. It is a huge list!!!

These keywords are set as green colour, as you can see the in the next picture, because this “instre1” is mapped to the style WORD, in the stylers.xml file.

[image]

Now, I want to colour the curly braces inside the strings, too.
Is this possible? I believe it is achievable by these keywords, but I have no idea which one should I use.

Comment: Thing you can't do this, because `Brace highlight style` is a `Global Style`.

Comment: But "Brace highlight style" is not including the curly braces inside strings.
I can tell this much, because the current setting colour is yellow. And in the image I posted, it isn't yellow. Edit: maybe I placed the wrong question: I want to colour them, not higlight them when I select, which happens so. Sorry

Comment: Only if you select it with you mouse it will be yellow. I have tested it.

Comment: Its little tricky i thing. Because i thing after the highlight of the braces (in any way) the content then within will be ignored. I have tryed to make a rule like `BRACED_STRING_VARIBALE` but i dnot get it work.

Comment: Look here sme issue: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/12290/bug-tcl-syntax-highlighting-double-quote-in-array-variable-reference

Comment: Looks like different issue. That problem happens when the quote is used after left parenthesis

Comment: Very special, what you want ;) I dont have ideas any more.